# Does keeping cyclomatic complexity between 5-10 makes unit testing easier?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, maintainability, code-maintainability

I'm planning to keep track of cyclomatic complexity for method and classes in between 5-10. 
Will it be easier to write unit tests if we keep it in that range?
Does it help us write effective unit tests which can be valuable in long run?

I know unit tests can be written properly without tracking cyclomatic complexity.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, because cyclomatic complexity does nothing else than counting the number of decisions in a function.

The more decisions you have the more branches you have to consider in your tests. Also keeping the cyclomatic complexity low will help you build software which has a higher maintainability because it more or less forces you to develop your function to be more atomic. Take this example:

You could either write one unit test which covers the following function with all its 3 possible branches:

```
foo(a, b, c) {
  if (a) {
    if (b && c) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 2;
  }
  return 3;
}
```

or you could split it up like this:

```
foo(a, b, c) {
  if (a) {
    return foo2(b, c);
  }
  return 3;
}

foo2(b, c) {
  if (b && c) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 2;
}
```

write two unit tests, one for function `foo2(b,c)` and if you write the unit test for function `foo(a,b,c)` you do not care about the correctness of `foo2(b,c)` anymore because you already tested it.

Long story short: cyclomatic complexity will not only increase testability but furthermore it will increase maintainability and readability of your code as well as other non-functional requirements.